# How to for-loop or while-loop a set a numbers like this

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to for-loop a set of numbers and change their positions in each line. It reads a series of integers (at most 10) until a non-integer has been inputted from the keyboard. My expected result is something like this:

```
>> 4 0 3 4 2 q
4 0 3 4 2
0 3 4 2 4 
3 4 2 4 0
4 2 4 0 3
2 4 0 3 4
```

Can anybody teach me how to deal with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where *exactly* are you stuck? Please post what you've tried, or perhaps try writing down on paper how you might do it.

Comment: I am stuck at the forlooping part. Can anybody answer my question and teach how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like homework. Why don't you post what you have so far, and you may get some help. None of the professional developers here are interested in writing your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

With some knowledge of modular arithmetic you can fold an array around into a circle. Observe that the starting point of each index shifts to the right by one place from the starting point of the previous row. So you do your loop like this:

```
n := length of the array
for i = 0 to n-1 (assuming the array is zero-based)
    j := i
    do loop
        print(array[j])
        j := j + 1
        j := j%n
    until j = i
end for
```

This is a language independent pseudo-code. Adapt it to whatever language your're coding in.

Comment: I've tried it but there are still errors. Can you show how to program it in java?

Comment: @alfred i can't do that until i know what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to shift the numbers like you want. I took the liberty of commenting it to give you a better understanding of what's going on.

```
public static void shift(int[] numbers) {
    //Store the first element
    int first = numbers[0];
    //Start for-loop at the beginning of the array, stop before the last element
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++)
        //Take the number at the next index (i + 1) and store it in the current index (i)
        numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
    //Don't forget about the first number!
    numbers[numbers.length - 1] = first;
}
```

The following snippet should change the contents of the array to be {0, 3, 4, 2, 4}

```
shift(new int[] {4, 0, 3, 4, 2})
```

Here is a complete, runnable class file.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Shift {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] {4, 0, 3, 4, 2};
        shift(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

    public static void shift(int[] numbers) {
        //Store the first element
        int first = numbers[0];
        //Start for-loop at the beginning of the array, stop before the last element
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++)
            //Take the number at the next index (i + 1) and store it in the current index (i)
            numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
        //Don't forget about the first number!
        numbers[numbers.length - 1] = first;
    }
}
```

#### EDIT:

To use an `ArrayList` called `list`, you can use the following snippet:

```
list.add(list.remove(0));
```

This is because `ArrayList.remove(int)` will return the object removed from the array, so we can just add it on to the end.

Comment: Can you clearly show how you type it in java? It doesnt work when I typed it in my programme.

Comment: But how about using an arrayList? Because I want this programme to be run for all integers, thanks!

Comment: Using an `ArrayList` would make this trivial. All you would need to do is use `list.add(list.remove(0))`;